# Error: cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate JUnitTestCase

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, checkstyle

After importing a maven project to Eclipse Luna the following error is displayed in a pop-up when saving after modifying a method:

> cannot initialize module TreeWalker - Unable to instantiate JUnitTestCase

JUnitTestCase is referring to a module in the checkstyle xml file:

```
<module name="JUnitTestCase"/>
```

I have the 'Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse' and 'Checkstyle Plug-in 6.4.0' installed. The plugin definition for 'maven-checkstyle-plugin' in my pom file specifies version 2.10.

**Note:** I realise this is similar to some other questions with the same error (but a different module specified) however I am yet to find a satisfying solution. I believe that I could remove the module entry in the checkstyle config file but I require it to work as designed so that is not the preferable option.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

JUnitTestCase was [removed in Checkstyle 6.2](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/releasenotes.html#Release_6.2) (look under "Breaking backward compatibility"). So you should either downgrade to Checkstyle 6.1.1, or remove the module reference from your *checkstyle.xml*.

Comment: Understood! I guess downgrading it will be.

Comment: How do I downgrade it in Eclipse?

Comment: @Marco This should be a separate question, but the answer is that you downgrade by installing [Eclipse-CS 6.1.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-cs/files/Eclipse%20Checkstyle%20Plug-in/6.1.1/).